# Dynamic/Recursive SQL Order By

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm building a Queue Plugin for a wordpress theme im working on. I'm using a single-directional linked list to accomplish this. Each row has a "previous_item_id" column in the db that POINTS to the row that should be printed BEFORE IT!  In need of an ODRDER BY wizard lol please and thank you

Current DB table:

```
ID     EMAIL           PREVIOUS_ITEM_ID
1      test@gmail.com     NULL
2      test2@gmail.com    1
3      test3@gmail.com    4
4      test4@gmail.com    2
5      test5@gmail.com    3
```

How can I write a SQL statement that uses Order By to grab the next row by `previous_item_id` like this:

- the first item should have no `previous_item_id`(Which makes it first)
- the second item should have 1 as the previous_item_id
- the third item should have 2 as the previous item_id
- the fourth item should have 3 as the previous_item_id

You basically take the initial row with NULL for `previous_item_id` and then recursively grab the next row by the ID.

The output of the order by should print:
What should be printed out:

```
test@gmail.com
test2@gmail.com
test4@gmail.com
test3@gmail.com
test5@gmail.com
```

Comment: How is the tag `sql server` relevant to a wordpress plugin? (only use tags that are directly related to your question)

Comment: Your description and your results do not match.

Comment: How so? it starts at the row with null and then needs to return the row with the first rows previous_item_id

Comment: You mean you want to order by previous id?

Comment: This question is illogical. @Gordon Linoff is correct. Consider your fourth item, the item with EMAIL 'test3@gmail.com' it has PREVIOUS_ITEM_ID = 4 not 3 as your description states. An arbitrary linked lists will not have its keys in ascending consecutive order.

Comment: @magenta . . . I think that's a mistake.  The bulleted list afterwards has a different result.

Comment: Even if that mistake can be corrected, it cannot be that in an arbitrary linked list the keys will be in ascending consecutive order.

Comment: Basically, ORDER BY cannot be used to solve this problem as ORDER BY needs a field or expression to sort the items. In an arbitrary linked list this field or expression does not exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done. The underlying data structure is an arbitrary linked list. ORDER BY needs an expression to sort the items in the data structure. In an arbitrary linked list this expression does not exists.

Please note that part of the question is not logically correct.

```
the first item should have no previous_item_id(Which makes it first)
the second item should have 1 as the previous_item_id
the third item should have 2 as the previous item_id
the fourth item should have 3 as the previous_item_id
```

In an arbitrary linked list the keys are not necessarily in consecutive ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case expression` such as this:

```
order by case when PREVIOUS_ITEM_ID IS NULL then 0 else PREVIOUS_ITEM_ID end

MAIL               
test@gmail.com 
test2@gmail.com 
test4@gmail.com 
test5@gmail.com 
test3@gmail.com
```

Comment: Sorry, how will that grab the next row by the `previous_item_id` value?

Comment: You asked for an order, I  supplied one.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the previous item id using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.id
        from t t2
        where t2.id < t.id
        order by t2.id desc
        limit 1
       ) as prev_id
from t;
```

Comment: Would this work with 1 table or 2? Sorry, im not too sure how to apply this to the situation described above

Comment: @rwchampin . . . This works on one table.  `t` is the table name.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and what about the t2?

Comment: @rwchampin . . . That is a table alias for the second reference to your table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT yourtable.email
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY previous_item_id
```

Fortunately you don't need recursion because all the records are relevant. If there are some other keys just add them to the where.